# Correct ISO value for AVFoundation camera

Tags: ios, avfoundation, iso

While working with `AVFoundation` I use these two properties to know the minimum and the maximum ISO a device camera can use:

```
AVCaptureDeviceFormat *activeFormat = _videoDevice.activeFormat;
minISO = activeFormat.minISO;
maxISO = activeFormat.maxISO;
```

But these lines give me the following results back:

```
minISO = 23
maxISO = 736
```

But there is no such thing as ISO 23 or 736. In fact, if you adjust the camera with ISO 23 it will adjust itself for ISO 50 and ISO 736 will make the camera adjust to ISO 800.

Is there a way to know the real ISOs a given camera can use before setting it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a list of standards ISO values:

```swift
let isos: [Float] = [32, 50, 64, 80, 100, 125, 160, 200, 250, 320, 400, 500, 640, 800, 1000, 1250, 1600, 1800]
```

And after initialization of capture device filter by min and max ISO values:

```swift
var isos_available: [Float] = []
    
for one_iso in isos {
    if one_iso >= min_iso && one_iso <= max_iso {
        isos_available.append(one_iso)
    }
}
```

Also for the shutter speed:

```swift
var shutters: [Float] = [1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 30, 60, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000]
var shutters_available: [Float] = []
    
let min_seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.device.activeFormat.minExposureDuration)
let max_seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.device.activeFormat.maxExposureDuration)
    
for one_shutter in shutters {
    let seconds = 1.0 / Float64(one_shutter)
    if seconds >= min_seconds && seconds <= max_seconds {
        shutters_available.append(one_shutter)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the *film speed*. The most common ISO values start at 25, and the following values are doubles (e. g. 50, 100, 200, 400). [Wikipedia: Film Speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_speed#Current_system:_ISO) lists all values.

Comment: OK, I know that, what I mean is this: one particular device can allow a range from 50 to 800 but as the iPhone/iPad evolves, it can go from 25 to 1600, 3200, 6400, etc. Unless I build a list of possible ISOs up to an absurd value and compare it but that seems like a hack that can be easily break. I was expected to receive an array of possible values, but whatever. Thanks anyway.